# PHP get variable from string and change its value

Tags: php

How to change the value of a variable that gets from the string?

```
<?php
    $a1 = array( 1, 2, 3 );
    $b = "a" . 1;
    $c = ${$b};
    for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $c[] = $i;
    }
    print_r($a1);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($c);
    echo "<br>";
?>
```

result

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 3 [7] => 4 [8] => 5 )
```

the variable $a1 will not be update from the value that has been add to $c. how to add the value?

Comment: I see that you have accepted an answer, but I find your question to be Unclear because you have not clearly stated your desired output.  Please edit your question.  99.999999% of the time, if you are using variable variables, you are processing array-like data in a fashion that cannot enjoy the benefits of php's array functionality. I would like to advise an alternative solution, but first I must understand your task.  Please also include _why_ you are preparing/storing your data this way.

Comment: Is your input array data coming from somewhere else or are declaring it as posted?  Where are your oitput arrays going? Displaying to HTML? Storing in DB?

Comment: To access array using string and add value to it. I can access the array using switch but have to declare each array variable. Using this way i only have to declare once for all array i have. Input data is come from modbus device, i need to create a table base on the value from the device

Comment: I wish I could see more of your code and more realistic data.  There is likely to be a better design.  You need to update `$a1` and `$c` or only `$a1`?  How is the `$b` value determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP performs copy-on-write:

```
$c = ${$b};                     // $c points to $a1
for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $c[] = $i;                  // since $c will be modified, it will get a copy of $a1
}

// $a1 and $c will be completely different variables
```

The behaviour you desire can be done with references (`$c = &${$b};`), but unless you have a strong reason, I'd recommend using separate variable values - and better named variables.
The reason is that reference variables look no different than regular ones (except the ampersand), so they're more prone to mistakes.

---

Notes

- you might find [debug_zval_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php) useful.
- more info on variables, references and copy-on-right: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [assignment by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference):

```
$c = &${$b};
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/U8xILp)